# Select one class in a Svelte component?

Tags: svelte-3

```
<script>
export let text
</script>

<button>
  {text}
</button>

<style>
:global(.bg-primary) {
    background-color: red ;
}
:global(.bg-secondary {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

When I import my component inside another component I would like to setup the background color with a prop

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
export let text
export let type = 'secondary'
</script>

<button class="bg-{type}">
 {text}
</button>
```

or

```html
<button class:bg-primary={type === 'primary'}  class:bg-secondary={type === 'secondary'}>
 {text}
</button>
```

The second approach limits the number of classes and works better with svelte unused class checking.